# Error handling in chained AngularJS promises

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to wrap my head around error handling in chained AngularJS promises.
I'm aware of this success/failure syntax:

```
        .then( function( departure )
        {
            $scope.departure = departure;                               // Response Handler #1
            return travelService.getFlight( departure.flightID );       // Request #2
        }, function( error )
        {
          //handle error
        })
```

However, I don't know how to apply that to a chain like this:

```
var FlightDashboard = function( $scope, user, flightService, weatherService )
{
    travelService
        .getDeparture( user )                                           // Request #1
        .then( function( departure )
        {
            $scope.departure = departure;                               // Response Handler #1
            return travelService.getFlight( departure.flightID );       // Request #2
        })
        .then( function( flight )
        {
            $scope.flight = flight;                                     // Response Handler #2
            return weatherService.getForecast( $scope.departure.date ); // Request #3
        })
        .then( function( weather )
        {
            $scope.weather = weather;                                   // Response Handler #3
        });
};
```

What if I need an error handling function for any or all of those 3 requests.
Would it then look like this? and if it does do I need to return anything from the error handlers?

```
var FlightDashboard = function( $scope, user, flightService, weatherService )
{
    travelService
        .getDeparture( user )                                           // Request #1
        .then( function( departure )
        {
            $scope.departure = departure;                               // Response Handler #1
            return travelService.getFlight( departure.flightID );       // Request #2
        }, function( error )
        {
          //handle request 1 error
        })
        .then( function( flight )
        {
            $scope.flight = flight;                                     // Response Handler #2
            return weatherService.getForecast( $scope.departure.date ); // Request #3
        }, function( error )
        {
          //handle request 2 error
        })
        .then( function( weather )
        {
            $scope.weather = weather;                                   // Response Handler #3
        }, function( error )
        {
          //handle request 3 error
        });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes like the success function, error handling function too needs to return a value. The promise returned by the `then` function is resolved by the return value of `success` or `error` callback.

A quirk here is that if we do a normal return in error callback, the promises further in the chain will always get resolved to `sucess`. If you want to propagate the promise are rejected promise further down the promise chain, you need to return a rejected promise in `error` callback. Like this:

```
var FlightDashboard = function( $scope, user, flightService, weatherService )
{
    travelService
        .getDeparture( user )                                           // Request #1
        .then( function( departure )
        {
            $scope.departure = departure;                               // Response Handler #1
            return travelService.getFlight( departure.flightID );       // Request #2
        }, function( error )
        {
            return $q.reject(error)
        })
        .then( function( flight )
        {
            $scope.flight = flight;                                     // Response Handler #2
            return weatherService.getForecast( $scope.departure.date ); // Request #3
        }, function( error )
        {
            return $q.reject(error)
        })
        .then( function( weather )
        {
            $scope.weather = weather;                                   // Response Handler #3
        }, function( error )
        {
            return $q.reject(error)
        });
};
```